# Can't connect to MySQL for .NET application deployed in Wine using Ubuntu

Tags: c#, mysql, ubuntu, mono, wine

Below is the link

[How to insert,delete,select,update values in datagridview in C# using MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518946/how-to-insert-delete-select-update-values-in-datagridview-in-c-using-mysql)

which has the code to connect to a MySQL datbase from a Windows application. It works fine in Windows XP. So I have created a setup file and installed in Ubuntu using [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29).

The issue is with the data not getting popped up in the datagridview of the application.

Extra information:

> > Wine is working fine by which i have installed small desktop application
> >     MySql with connector,Mono IDE are already installed.
> >
> > > It is even possible for me to create small applications using mono>(excluding database)

Screenshot 1:
In Windows it looks like this:

[image]

But in Ubuntu Linux(8.04) it doesn't show up and looks like below.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I don't have full answer for you, but from the error it looks like something to do with character encoding of the data maybe.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libmono-i18n2.0-cil I used the above command. Because of which the error got segregated. But Still the error pops up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI all,

Thanks for the all the help and support from all of you.

I have installed crossover trail version which supports datagridview.
Please follow the link to find the answer.

http://www.talkonsomething.com/2009/11/how-to-connect-mysql-database-from-windows-xp-to-ubuntu/

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like [bug 33938](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33938), the Mono environment in Linux doesn't seem to support Windows' [native codepage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (1252).

Comment: This is a problem with the way debian and ubuntu package Mono, not with the framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, why are you using Wine and Mono at the same time? That probably won't work. Why don't you run the application natively, using only Mono?

Comment: I have used many other technologies like crystal reports, access. I think mono isn't capable of supporting such applications

Comment: Do not run Mono on Wine, this is pointless! And what version of Mono are you using? The bug mentioned by @unwind is in version that is two years old at least.

Comment: I'm not running Mono on Wine but creating a .exe file from windows(visual studio.net) and then deploying in linux ubuntu using wine. This is working fine for small applications, but for database applications errors are popping up