# how to run crystal reports in ubuntu linux

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports, ubuntu

I am trying to use the crystal reports application in ubuntu. So far i was able to connect the MYSQL database using c# in .net platform and run a small application in ubuntu over crossover linux.

But when i try to fetch the data from mysql database and display in crystal reports i get an error as shown in the below picture:

[alt text http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/3282/screenshot2i.jpg](http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/3282/screenshot2i.jpg)

[alt text http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/3504/screenshot1my.png](http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/3504/screenshot1my.png)

This thread is an extension of the below thread.

[Can't connect to MySQL for .NET application deployed in Wine using Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686852/cant-connect-to-mysql-for-net-application-deployed-in-wine-using-ubuntu)

Comment: take another screenshot, this time.. click details so we can see the stacktrace

Comment: Are you able to run the report in Crystal Reports Developer?

Comment: Can we install the Crystal Reports Developer in ubuntu. If so please send me the link where i can download and install

Comment: Are you permanently-tied to Crystal Reports? If not, have you considered a cross-platform tool like BIRT (http://eclipse.org/birt/)?

Comment: I need crystal reports desperately. Is it possible for birt tool to generate reports in ubuntu with c# as programming language and mysql as its backend database.b'coz i see that birt is built for java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by my own after doing a small research.

The error was due the licensing problem of visual studio .net 2005. The following packages had to be configured in Merge Reports (i.e C:\Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules)

Crystal_Managed2003.msm
Crystal_Database_Access2003.msm
Crystal_Database_Access2003_enu.msm
Crystal_regwiz2003.msm

And then we need to enter the license key while deploying the application correctly.

Later the following packages would be installed automatically when we run the deployed .net application in ubuntu linux

Refer screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The WineHQ [db claims that it will run.](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17446) However, if you do intend to target the Linux and Windows platforms, I would suggest a more cross platform compatible library.

Comment: I am using crossover platform in the trail version. It still shows the same error

Comment: I think he means, don't use crystal reports if cross platform is your goal. (i.e. something that must run through wine is not cross platform)