# can we deploy an asp.net web application developed in windows in ubuntu

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, ubuntu, wine

We have developed a web application in windows using visual studio 2005. Is it possible to deploy that application in linux using crossover. Is it possible to run crystal reports in asp.net using crossover.

I have used wine, and cross over and even mono. But it was not possible for me to develop crystal reports web application in ubuntu.

But I am able to develop windows application using c# with mysql database as backend and have used crystal reports. But it doesn't work for ubuntu

Please look at the below posts for more details:

[how to run crystal reports in ubuntu linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781229/how-to-run-crystal-reports-in-ubuntu-linux)

[Can't connect to MySQL for .NET application deployed in Wine using Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686852/cant-connect-to-mysql-for-net-application-deployed-in-wine-using-ubuntu)

http://www.talkonsomething.com/2009/11/how-to-connect-mysql-database-from-windows-xp-to-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Well, maybe.

You will probably have more luck with Mono than wine, but either way you're looking for pain.

Good luck.

Comment: I am tired working on this crossover, wine and mono. Hopefully Microsoft gets pity on me and develops much better cross platform application which would be subordinate to visual studio in linux

Comment: Microsoft, supporting web application deployment on Linux? Are we talking about the same company?

Comment: No the crossover and open source people have some issues with Microsoft over licensing. So was just kidding hoping microsoft would understand open source developer's issues

Comment: @Srikanth - It's not the open source people who have issues with Microsoft, it's Microsoft who have issues with the entire concept of standards, competition, fairness and freedom in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can now install visual studio code in Linux and compile it there. Microsoft's [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) is an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) with support for Mac, Linux and Windows.

Comment: No, Visual Studio Code doesn't ship with a compiler, nor is the full .net framework available for Linux/Mac.

Answer (score 0):

As Shoham mentioned, Microsoft recently released Visual Studio Code, a lightweight, cross platform code editor. However, this doesn't exactly get you all the way to fully deploying .NET code on Ubuntu. In order to do that you also need to install the [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) and the [ASP.NET 5](https://github.com/aspnet/home). I've been trying to do exactly this in OS X, which should be very similar, but haven't quite gotten it working yet.